# T test between two numbers(0.85,0.18) getting p value as Nan

Tags: python, statistics, t-test

t-test between two numbers (0.85,0.18) getting p-value as `Nan` along with the following error:

> Getting this error also
> _,p_value=stats.ttest_ind(a=Max,b=Max_1,equal_var=False)
> C:\Users\NehaBhakat\Anaconda31\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3584: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
> **kwargs)
> C:\Users\NehaBhakat\Anaconda31\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py:903: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
> return (a < x) & (x < b)
> C:\Users\NehaBhakat\Anaconda31\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py:903: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
> return (a < x) & (x < b)
> C:\Users\NehaBhakat\Anaconda31\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py:1912: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
> cond2 = cond0 & (x <= _a)

Comment: See also stats.stackexchange.com for discussion about concepts.

Answer (score 2):

A t-test is for finding out whether two **distributions** are in fact coming from the same population. You cannot test for two single values. Hence, getting NaN is correct.

A distribution means, that you have a vector with values that you measured. To have a meaningful t-test, you should usually have at least 30 values.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.stats.ttest_ind()` runs a t-test on two samples, testing the null hypothesis that 2 independent samples have **identical average (expected) values** . It expects you to pass the two samples (group a, group b) as arrays of all the observations, so it can calculate the pooled standard deviation. See the formula it uses below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test))

[image: two sample t test formula]

To calculate the standard deviation we need the difference of every point from the mean, that's why it's asking you for the whole array of data.
The [Scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) explains what the function expects as well:

> a, b array_like
> The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default).